# The year of the customer's continuous subscription with our company (Year 1, Year 2, Year 3, Year 4 etc)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I need your help finding the year of the customer's continuous subscription with our company (Year 1, Year 2, Year 3, Year 4 etc)

Let's say we have monthly data about if a customer is active

| account_id | month-year | active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-07-1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-08-1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-09-1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-10-1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-11-1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-12-1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-1-1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-2-1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-3-1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-4-1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2019-5-1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2019-6-1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2019-7-1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2019-8-1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2019-9-1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2019-10-1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2019-11-1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2019-11-1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2019-12-1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2020-1-1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2020-2-1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2020-3-1 | 1 |
| . |  |  |
| . |  |  |
| . |  |  |
| etc. |  |  |

If an account churns for up to 4 months and then becomes again a customer is acceptable to include this year as a subscription year

The RDBMS is Amazon Redshift.

Thank you in advance.

Had no luck so far. Thus, I need your help.

Comment: Please share the desired output in plain txt

Comment: Hi @KaziMohammadAliNurRomel. The desired output should be  Account 1 Year 2

Comment: account 2 year 1? if an customer is active at December can we considered that year as subscription year?

Comment: Yes!! but only if the next month is active. The customer should be active right now too. So older data may be irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

To find the year of a customer's continuous subscription with your company, taking into account up to 4 months of churn, you can use the following SQL query:

```
    WITH subscription_periods AS (
  SELECT
    account_id,
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(month_year, 'YYYY-MM')) AS subscription_year,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY TO_DATE(month_year, 'YYYY-MM')) AS period_rank
  FROM
    your_table_name
  WHERE
    active = 1
), continuous_subscriptions AS (
  SELECT
    account_id,
    subscription_year,
    period_rank - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account_id, subscription_year ORDER BY period_rank) AS subscription_group
  FROM
    subscription_periods
)
SELECT
  account_id,
  subscription_year,
  MIN(subscription_group) AS subscription_start,
  MAX(subscription_group) + 1 AS subscription_end,
  MAX(subscription_group) - MIN(subscription_group) + 1 AS subscription_duration
FROM
  continuous_subscriptions
GROUP BY
  account_id,
  subscription_year,
  subscription_group
ORDER BY
  account_id,
  subscription_year,
  subscription_start;
```

In this query, we first create a CTE (Common Table Expression) called subscription_periods to extract the year from the month_year column and assign a row number to each period within each account. Then, we use another CTE called continuous_subscriptions to determine the subscription groups based on the difference between the period rank and the row number.

Finally, we select the account ID, subscription year, subscription start, subscription end, and subscription duration by grouping the data from the continuous_subscriptions CTE.

The query will give you the account ID, subscription year, start and end periods of each subscription, and the duration of each subscription in months.